# Cross referencing in require js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have problem where my requirejs modules are cross referencing and interacting with each other.

Here is example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTrVw/)

First module will take the second module values, why requirejs is behaving like that?

---

HTML:

```
<div id="first">
    <input data-bind="value: user.Name" />
    <input data-bind="value: user.Age" />
    <button data-bind="click: editUser">Edit</button>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <input data-bind="value: user.Name" />
    <input data-bind="value: user.Age" />
    <button data-bind="click: saveUser">Save</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
define('vm',
      [
          'vm.edit',
          'vm.save'
          ],
       function(edit,save){
           return{
               save: save,
               edit: edit
           }
       });
define('vm.save',function(){
 var self = this;
    self.user = {
        Name: ko.observable(),
        Age: ko.observable()
    }

    var saveUser = function() {
     alert(self.user.Name() + " is age of " + self.user.Age());   
    }

    return {
        saveUser: saveUser,
        user: user
    }
});

define('vm.edit',function(){
 var self = this;
    self.user = {
        Name: ko.observable(),
        Age: ko.observable()
    }

    var editUser = function() {
     alert(self.user.Name() + " is age of " + self.user.Age());   
    }

    return {
        editUser: editUser,
        user: user
    }
})

require(['vm'],function(vm){
ko.applyBindings(vm.save, document.getElementById("second"));
    ko.applyBindings(vm.edit, document.getElementById("first"));
})
```

Comment: Sure this is a require issue and not a Knockout binding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The require.js part of this appears to be working fine. I think the issue is how you get the reference to the active object when the button is clicked. If you do something like this I think you will get the right value:

```
var saveUser = function(v) {
 alert(v.user.Name() + " is age of " + v.user.Age());   
}

var editUser = function(v) {
 alert(v.user.Name() + " is age of " + v.user.Age());   
}
```

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html):

> When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model value as the first parameter. This is particularly useful if you’re rendering some UI for each item in a collection, and you need to know which item’s UI was clicked.